# ASP.NET MVC [RequireHttps] - return to http

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, requirehttps

Once you place `[RequireHttps]` on an action and user switches from HTTP to HTTPS, all subsequent links will stay HTTPS...

Is there a way to switch back to HTTP ?

Comment: This can be done with filters. Try searching SO, there are many questions almost exactly the same as yours.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**Technically, you could do it**

You could [look at the source](http://aspnet.codeplex.com/releases/view/58781) of `RequireHttpsAttribute` and reverse it.

**In practice, you probably shouldn't**

If the session is still alive, [it is generally inadvisable to return to HTTP](http://ferruh.mavituna.com/ssl-implementation-security-faq-oku/#_Toc198392034). This can be the [foundation for a variety of attacks](http://mashable.com/2011/05/31/https-web-security/), for example, [session hijacking](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/Session_hijacking_attack).

Comment: Thanks for all the links - I generally agree with you, but I have a "contact us" page for which I'd like to enforce SSL - the rest of the site is informational.

Comment: @zam6ak No problem. You'll be OK if the rest of the site is only informational, but what do you hope to gain by returning to HTTP?

Comment: I read somewhere that switching schemes "hurts" SEO. Unfortunately, I don't have link the article anymore, and I am not 100% sure if that is true...

Answer (score 2):

there is a pretty detailed description of how to handle switching from HTTPS back to HTTP for specific action methods at this link

http://blog.clicktricity.com/2010/03/switching-to-https-and-back-to-http-in-asp-net-mvc/

Answer (score 1):

Here's the 'ExitHttpsIfNotRequired' attribute I use:

```
[AttributeUsage(AttributeTargets.Class | AttributeTargets.Method)]
public class RetainHttpsAttribute : Attribute
{
}

public class ExitHttpsIfNotRequiredAttribute : FilterAttribute, IAuthorizationFilter
{
    public void OnAuthorization(AuthorizationContext filterContext)
    {
        // Abort if it's not a secure connection  
        if (!filterContext.HttpContext.Request.IsSecureConnection) return;

        if (filterContext.ActionDescriptor.ControllerDescriptor.ControllerName == "sdsd") return;

        // Abort if it's a child controller
        if (filterContext.IsChildAction) return;

        // Abort if a [RequireHttps] attribute is applied to controller or action  
        if (filterContext.ActionDescriptor.ControllerDescriptor.GetCustomAttributes(typeof(RequireHttpsAttribute), true).Length > 0) return;
        if (filterContext.ActionDescriptor.GetCustomAttributes(typeof(RequireHttpsAttribute), true).Length > 0) return;

        // Abort if a [RetainHttps] attribute is applied to controller or action  
        if (filterContext.ActionDescriptor.ControllerDescriptor.GetCustomAttributes(typeof(RetainHttpsAttribute), true).Length > 0) return;
        if (filterContext.ActionDescriptor.GetCustomAttributes(typeof(RetainHttpsAttribute), true).Length > 0) return;

        // Abort if it's not a GET request - we don't want to be redirecting on a form post  
        if (!String.Equals(filterContext.HttpContext.Request.HttpMethod, "GET", StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase)) return;

        // Abort if the error controller is being called - we may wish to display the error within a https page
        if (filterContext.ActionDescriptor.ControllerDescriptor.ControllerName == "Error") return;

        // No problems - redirect to HTTP
        string url = "http://" + filterContext.HttpContext.Request.Url.Host + filterContext.HttpContext.Request.RawUrl;
        filterContext.Result = new RedirectResult(url);
    }
}
```